# Zero crossing detector output to another optocoupler

Tags: opto-isolator, plc, voltage-detector

I will use the configuration below to build a zero crossing detector to connect to a PLC.

I will change the output voltage to 24VDC and the correspondig resistor to 50K.

The problem is that the input port in the PLC contains a PC817 optoisolator and I am not sure if the optoisolator will repeat the input signal.

Have you ever done this configuration connecting the output signal to an optoisolator? Will it work? If I put a LED as test light will it flash? How many optoisolators can be concatenated?

[image: ZERO CROSSING DETECTOR]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Here is how you would wire it for a PNP input but it probably isn't going to be much good. For NPN connect the top terminal to the input and the bottom terminal to ground.*

It's not clear what you are trying to do but most PLCs have a scan time in the order of 2 to 20 ms. 50 Hz mains has a zero-cross every 10 ms and 60 Hz every 8.33 ms. As a result your PLC probably won't detect the zero-cross unless you are using a high-speed or interrupt input.

Comment: And also, the spikes here are very short - even a 1ms scan time may not be enough.

Comment: i am using that PLC BOARD to control motor speed, is based on STC12C5A602 MCU, the only problem with those PLC BOARDS are hard to write the program: http://more-suns.com/product/html/?321.html

Comment: You've linked to an ad page rather than the datasheet which I can't find. Am I right in thinking that it's a Mitsubishi FX PLC emulator? What are you making that you want zero-cross detection? That would be considered very unusual in PLC applicaions.

Comment: those PLC boards use an STC12C5A60S2 MCU, its datasheet can be download from here: http://www.stcmicro.com/sjsc.html

Answer (score 1):

The pulse width (those spikey things in the diagram) will be of the order of 300usec if I did the trig correctly (assuming a typical CTR of 50%-- minimum is 20%-- and LED Vf of ~1.2V).

\$p_{wid}\$ \$\approx\$ \$2\sin^{-1}({1.5/24})\cdot (1/\omega)\$ where \$\omega\$ = \$2\pi\cdot f\$

If your PLC can respond to a pulse of (say) 100usec, say with an interrupt or a counter input, it should work. A normal PLC scanned input won't reliably pick anything up.

Comment: great, i will check those number first

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this complication is for. **All you need is literally a diode (1N4007)** in series from one end of the winding to the PLC input - forward polarized for NPN inputs (active high), reverse polarized for PNP inputs (active low), and connect the other side of the winding to PLC's ground. That's all. I assume that the 24VAC winding is dedicated to the detection function.

If the winding is used to power the PLC using a full bridge, then you only need to connect one end of the winding via a diode to the PLC's input, polarized as above. The other end is already connected to the PLC's common (0V) bus via the rectifier bridge.

If the winding is *not* used to power the PLC, but is used for something else, then you'll need another small line-to-24VAC transformer - it can be as small as you can get it, and make sure it's either a class 2 transformer (inherently impedance protected from overloads), or that you fuse the primary appropriately. Of course you can also use a small 1:1 isolation transformer designed for line frequency operation (50/60Hz); most small audio transformers will not be suitable since their low passband's 3dB cut-off point is well above line frequency and they'll attenuate the signal too much.

The circuit you present generates a train of narrow pulses, and those are quite hard to detect with typical multi-millisecond PLC cycle times - even 1ms is not enough to reliably catch those. So instead of pulses you want a simple square wave input at line frequency, and that's what the diode provides. Simple and efficient :)

Comment: i have aleady tried that, but looks like the time the signal is "on" take all pulse time and PLC stays in the same state, that is why a pulse signal is a better option. PLC uses a oscilator cristal with 11035MHz, enougth to process 60Hz signals